# Build Docker with artifacts in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I would like to do a Java build into pipeline artifact and then put it in docker file.
i can't figure out a way to add artifact to a dockerfile in one pipeline
I would like one pipeline to build java code and build a docker image with jar.

Answer (score 3):

> Azure DevOps Pipeline - build Docker with artifacts

You could set the target path to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` for the task build java code.

Then, add a Docker task after above the publish task, configured to "Build" and set the "Build Context" in the task to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`. That's the root path Docker will use for commands like COPY in a Dockerfile.

And set the Dockerfile path in the task to match its location:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myAppNameHere.dll"]
```

Since you've set the Docker Build Context to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, where your app has been published, the COPY command will use that as a "current working directory." The translation of the COPY is "copy everything in `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` to the `/app` folder inside the container."